# Django-REST: custom permission doesn't work

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I'm trying to make a custom permission using [this guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#adding-required-permissions-to-views)

**views.py**

```py
class CustomModelList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = CustomModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomModelSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsCustomOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # some logic

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # some logic
```

Just for experiment I've created this permission not to apply anyway

**pesmissions.py**

```py
class IsCustomOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return False
```

But when POST request sends to server it takes no effect -- I'm able to create new model instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that since you are using a list view, [custom object level permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) are not checked automatically.

> Also note that the generic views will only check the object-level permissions for views that retrieve a single model instance. If you require object-level filtering of list views, you'll need to filter the queryset separately. See the filtering documentation for more details.

You can try overriding the `has_permission` method instead and see if that works, or check the permissions manually.

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thanks